# Can I animate $anchorScroll ?

Tags: angularjs

I have been using $anchorScroll to jump from the top of the page to the bottom like so:

```
app.controller('homeCntl',
function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll){
    $scope.goToBottom = function() {
        $location.hash('bottomOfPage');
        $anchorScroll();
    }
});
```

Which works fine and it jumps to the bottom of the page.

It doesn't look great though and I was wondering if there was a way to add animations/transition effects to this?

or if I would just have to look at another approach like making a directive or using jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, `ngAnimate` does not support `$anchorScroll`. $anchorScroll itself does not expose any API to build animate upon, neither.